# Does raster interpolation recognize multiple z values for one x, y point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, interpolation, 3d, geology

I am working with lithological data, where I have multiple z depths for one set of coordinates. How is this read by the raster interpolation toolset? Does it utilize only one or all of these z values?

If it does not recognize multiple values, is there a type of interpolation I can use that can?

My ultimate goal is to create something in ArcScene that has a 3D appearance and can demonstrate the profundity of a certain lithology.

Comment: No, but Point to Raster isn't an interpolation method anyways. You could make a raster from each column (Toolbox>Spatial Analyst>Interpolation) and then run Toolbox>Data Management Tools>Raster>Raster Processing>Composite Bands.. but I don't think this will get you were you are hoping. An aside here... I remember doing routed data along vertical lines that I had to offset (by a millimeter) in order to get correct results. I assume there is some divide by zero errors that are not getting caught but ESRI :)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear - was using raster interpolation, just based on points. So I gather that the tool is probably only reading the uppermost value for the output?

Comment: Is the data for something like a geologic horizon? If so, are the multiple z values due measurement error, or deformation (fault/fold)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a 3D model of soil depth, keep the lowest z value per coordinate, and then, perform the interpolation. Then, visualize it in ArcScene.

---

> Does raster interpolation recognize multiple z values for one x, y point?

It depends. See what [ESRI](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/an-overview-of-the-interpolation-tools.htm) says about IDW, Kriging, Natural Neighbour, Spline and Trend.

> "Some input datasets may have several points with the same x,y coordinates. If the values of the points at the common location are the same, they are considered duplicates and have no effect on the output. If the values are different, they are considered coincident points.
>
> The various interpolation tools may handle this data condition differently. For example, in some cases, the first coincident point encountered is used for the calculation; in other cases, the last point encountered is used. This may cause some locations in the output raster to have different values than what you might expect. The solution is to prepare your data by removing these coincident points.".